# Find the top 5 MAX() values from an SQL table and then performi an AVG() on that table without them

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to perform an avg() on a column *after* removing the 5 highest values in it and see that the stddev is not above a certain number. This has to be done entirely as a PL/SQL query.

EDIT:
To clarify, I have a data set that contains values in a certain range and tracks latency. I want to know whether the AVG() of those values is due to a general rise in latency, or due to a few values with a very high stddev. I.e - (1, 2, 1, 3, 12311) as opposed to (122, 124, 111, 212). I also need to achieve this via an SQL query due to our monitoring software's limitations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to find the top 5 values, and filter them out in a `where` clause:

```
select  avg(col1)
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by col1 desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn > 5
```

Comment: I don't need to remove the top/bottom 5 rows from my data set. I need to remove the top 5 MAX() values. I.e - If my data set contains (111, 123, 1231, 15151, 12311, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1....) I want to perform an AVG() that returns the results of the single digits.

Comment: @Arkadi: His query does that. Note the `order by`.

Comment: Hmm. What I seem to be missing is what the over keyword exactly does. A quick google doesn't return much, except that it relates to partitioning your results, which seems very relevant. I'll try and look into that.

Comment: @Arkadi:  This is called an `analytic function`.  Documentation here:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm

Comment: This version will remove 5 rows with the highest value, not the 5 highest values. The difference is that if you have the same value more that once, each time it is removed will count as one removal.  If you change `row_number` to `dense_rank`, the five highest values will be removed, no matter how many times they occur.

Answer (score 2):

```
select column_name1 from 
(
  select column_name1 from table_name order by nvl(column_name,0) desc
)a 
where rownum<6
```

(the nvl is done to omit the `null` value if there is/are any in the column `column_name`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most efficient way to do it would be to calculate `(sum(all values) - sum(top 5 values)) / (row_count - 5)`

```
SELECT SUM(val) AS top5sum FROM table ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 5

SELECT SUM(val) AS allsum FROM table

SELECT (COUNT(*) - 5) AS bottomCount FROM table
```

The average is then `(allsum - top5sum) / bottomCount`

Comment: `LIMIT` is not available in Oracle

Answer (score -1):

First, get the MAX 5 values:

```
SELECT TOP 5 RowId FROM Table ORDER BY Column
```

Now use this in your main statement:

```
SELECT AVG(Column) FROM Table WHERE RowId NOT IN (SELECT TOP 5 RowId FROM Table ORDER BY Column)
```

Comment: `TOP` is not available in Oracle

Comment: In Oracle, `TOP` is replaced by `LIMIT`.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have TOP or LIMIT